# Get index in the list of objects by attribute in Python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have list of objects with attribute id and I want to find index of object with specific id. I wrote something like this:

```
index = -1
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if my_list[i].id == 'specific_id'
        index = i
        break
```

but it doesn't look very well. Are there any better options?

Comment: Looping by index is a really huge anti-pattern in Python - loop directly over a list.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use `enumerate` when you want both the values and indices in a `for` loop:

```
for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
    if item.id == 'specific_id':
        break
else:
    index = -1
```

Or, as a generator expression:

```
index = next((i for i, item in enumerate(my_list) if item.id == 'specific_id'), -1)
```

Comment: But "-1" is a valid index value. If your code doesn't find a match, it will return an index of -1, and lead someone to take the final element of the list as though it matched.

Comment: @CPBL That's true. It would certainly be more pythonic to raise a `ValueError` in the else clause (to mirror the behavior of `list.index`).

Answer (score 13):

Here's an alternative that doesn't use an (explicit) loop, with two different approaches to generating the list of 'id' values from the original list.

```
try:
    # index = map(operator.attrgetter('id'), my_list).index('specific_id')
    index = [ x.id for x in my_list ].index('specific_id')
except ValueError:
    index = -1
```

Comment: Is this in python 3 only?  Using python 2.7.4 'find' doesn't exist - the method that finds the index of an element in a list is called 'index'.

Comment: No, this just appears to be a disaster of an answer. Not only did I appear to assume there was a `list.find` by analogy to the pair of `str.find` and `str.index` methods, but also mixed up which one raises a `ValueError` (it's `str.index`, not `str.find`) and which returns -1. Corrected to `list.index` now.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
    if item.id == 'specific_id':
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

Implement the `__eq__` method for your class

```py
class MyCls:
   def __init__(self, id):
       self.id = id

   def __eq__(self, other):
       # comparing with str since you want to compare
       # your object with str

       if not isinstance(other, str):
           raise TypeError("MyCls can be compared only with str")
       if other == self.id:
           return True
       return False
```

now you can do something like

```
my_list = [MyCls(i) for i in 'abcdef']
print(my_list.index('c'))
```

This would return the index 2. It would behave like normal list.index methods behaves. i.e If it doesn't find the index, it will raise a ValueError

Answer (score -1):

Assuming

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
val = 3
```

Do

```
a.index(val) if val in a else -1
```

For multiple occurrence, as per Azam's comment below:

```
[i if val == x else -1 for i,x in enumerate(a)]
```

Edit1:
For everyone commenting that its List of object, all you need is, access the `id`

```
[i if val == x.id else -1 for i,x in enumerate(a)]
```

Comment: what if the val number that we are searching for is repeating such as a=[1,2,3,4,3,7,9]???

Comment: is a = [1,2,3,4] a  list of objects ? Please read the op's question before answering

Comment: this is not a list of objects