# Python List of element output is discontinuous

Tags: python

I knew when python's list append element,the element is appended to tail. I tried to output the element of the list, why the element's address is out of order? Please help me out,thanks!

```
list = []
list.append(2)
list.append(10)
list.append(3)
print('--append--')
for i in list:
    print('i:{}, id:{}'.format(i,id(i)))
```

the output is:

```
--append--
i:2, id:140711739437936
i:10, id:140711739438192
i:3, id:140711739437968
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get index in the list of objects by attribute in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162285/get-index-in-the-list-of-objects-by-attribute-in-python)

Comment: Did you look into what `id()` does? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id

Comment: The index of an element in a list and the `id` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function returns a unique id for the specified object.

You need to use the index of the list

```py
list = []
list.append(2)
list.append(10)
list.append(3)
print('--append--')
for i in list:
    print('i:{}, id:{}'.format(i,list.index(i))) # replace id with list.index
```

Comment: Thinks for your answer! May be I didn't describe clearly. 
The id() function returns the address of the object in memory. 
when I append element, the value of id should increase orderly, but why the memory address can't do this.

Comment: @small-orange I think, [this](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython#-strings-can-be-tricky-sometimes) concept will answer your question

Comment: Think you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[id()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)  returns identity (unique integer) of an object...

```
a=3
print(id(3)) #9752224
```

You can use this

```
list = []
list.append(2)
list.append(10)
list.append(3)
print('--append--')
for i in enumerate(list): #enumerate return an enumerate object.if list it [(0,2),(1,10),(2,3)]
    print('i:{}, id:{}'.format(i[1],i[0]))# for getting index number i[0]
```

Comment: Ok, I konw. Think you very much

Answer (score 0):

The `id` function is rarely used in actual programming, and usually, you use the list index to deal with lists. Your example will look something like:

```
mylist = []
mylist.append(2)
mylist.append(10)
mylist.append(3)
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
[2,10, 3]
```

Sample code:

```
for x in range(len(mylist)):
        print(x, mylist[x])
```

Output:

```
0, 2
1, 10
2, 3
```

You may check one of the good python tutorials on the web such as the one on the python web page: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: Ok, I konw. Think you very much.